# Pytest Ignore Warning in Fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I have a fixture that I am using:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def dask_client():
    cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=None, threads_per_worker=2)
    client = Client(cluster)
return client

def test_some_func(x, dask_client):
    # Do something
    return
```

But it is causing a warning due to the first line in the above function call. Normally, I could ignore warnings on individual tests by adding the following decorator to a test:

```
@pytest.mark.filterwarnings("ignore:some regex to match")
```

However, this seems to have no effect on fixtures when I decorate the fixture with this decorator. I've also tried decorating the test function with this line as well but without any luck. How do I catch and ignore the warning that comes as a result of calling the fixture?

Answer (score -1):

Use --disable-warnings flag in the your pytest marker cmd to suppress all the warnings.
About catching those warnings, you can refer official documentation : https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html

Comment: But I don't want to suppress warnings as this would be dangerous. I would rather catch and handle all of the warnings that I expect so that I can see and understand when things go wrong.

Comment: You can create separate marker to handle errors. As shown in the link '@pytest.mark.filterwarnings'.